# storing database in version control

Tags: database, git, version-control

I am using a version control system to manage my wordpress code (git). What is the betst way to store the database information into version control?

I want to go to my staging machine, run `git pull` to get the latest code from my development machine, then maybe click one button or something like that to update the DB to match what I have on my development computer.

I also want a way to, on my stage machine, "merge" the my development DB with the production DB before pushing all of that to production.

so:

1. how to update a DB after a `git pull`
2. how to "merge" DB information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a git question than a WordPress one IMHO, but what you need to do is write a [bash script](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html%20%7C) and associate with a [git hook](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html) that does what you want.

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing how you went with this, @Alexander Bird. Perhaps you might want to add an answer with what you ended up with?